# couchbase - how to set queryView options in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, couchbase-lite

Function couchbase.getDatabase().queryView() always returns all rows. I can't find the way to set options properly.

```
let options = {
  key: ["First", "1"],
  include_docs: true
}

 this.couchbase.getDatabase().queryView("_design/dispatch", "orders", options)
 .then(result => {
   console.log(result)});
}
```

My view in couchbase.ts:

```
     let views = {
          orders: {
            map: function(doc) {
              if (doc.type == "orders" && doc.district) {
                emit([doc.district, doc.done], {
                  name: doc.name,
                  rev: doc._rev
                });
              }
            }.toString()
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your map function that you're emitting an array for the key.  You've specified the key as an array of single keys, not an array to match your index.  So you need

```
let options = {
  key: [["First", "1"]],
  include_docs: true
}
```

`queryView` is just a light wrapper around a call using a `$http` object.  Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
queryView: function(designDocumentName, viewName, options) {
  return this.makeRequest("GET", this.databaseUrl + this.databaseName + "/" + designDocumentName + "/_view/" + viewName, options);
}
```

So you can see it's using a GET call to the design doc REST endpoint.

If you're having trouble debugging the issue, you might want to try using curl commands against the Sync Gateway API.  That's easier to do (and see log output, etc.)  It's much like the Couchbase Lite API.  Take a look at the docs [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/references/sync-gateway/index.html).